# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (final release)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using Angular2 `2.1.0`. When I want to display a list of companies, I got this error.

in `file.component.ts` :

```js
public companies: any[] = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];
```

In `file.component.html` :

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of companies; let i =index">
     <td>{{i}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: make sure you not made a typo too `ngfor` gives the error you mentioned. Should be `ngFor`

Comment: angular is case sensitive too.

Comment: Just lost ~1h on this error, on just one specific page. Tried all the answers here, but finally the solution was to rebuild the whole thing with ng, the problem just disappeared...

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of failed plugin in IDE (VS Code, Web Storm). Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368326/4079915

Comment: I added my FileComponent to declarations and it works.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FileComponent
  ],

Comment: CHECK here, if you've No solution of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644077/5114465

Comment: in my case, i generated component by hand (not using 'ng g c') and forgot to declare it in the app.module

Comment: Please once check if the component is present in declarations array of Module or not. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Add `BrowserModule` to `imports: []` in `@NgModule()` if it's the root module (`AppModule`), otherwise the `CommonModule`.

```ts
// older Angular versions
// import {BrowserModule, CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
..
..
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, /* or CommonModule */],
  ..
})
```

Comment: Is it your only module or do you have more than one? `BrowserModule` is only for the root module.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? (Plunker provides a ready to use Angular2 TS template).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the CommonModule is located in '@angular/common' so you must make sure to add

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'

Comment: I had similar issue. my app has multiple modules, the import Browser module statement needs to be added in app module and in another module.

Comment: @ssmsnet Importing `BrowserModule` in other modules than `AppModule` is invalid. In other modules `CommonModule` needs to be imported. You should get an error message if you import `BrowserModule` in other modules.

Comment: I needed to import `BrowserModule` in a child module to get the `*ngFor` directive working, and I had it in the root too. `CommonModule` is the correct one to import tho, but both modules worked in my child module. No compile error (with angular `5.0.5`)

Comment: I don't think there was a related change. You should get an error https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.1/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L95

Comment: sometimes it can be a simple typo, the same error happens when doing "*ngFor="let passenger or passengers" <--- notice: "or" should be "of" ;-)

Comment: In the new version of Angular the `BrowserModule` is part of `@angular/platform-browser`. Therefor, you must import as: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'`

Comment: N.b.: If you get that warning in a unit test, even though you have imported the `CommonModule`, check for dynamically loaded components and ensure that those are also added to your test harness. The compiler possibly omits the `CommonModule` when it is only used in a dynamic component (due to tree shaking).

Comment: I had similar issue, But even after trying this it was still not working!

 I have multiple modules, I forgot to import the "other module"  into my "root module" and that was breaking a few of my imports including the `CommonModule` and it was giving me this same error. Thanks for you @Günter this helped me narrow it down and find my real problem. 

Hope this extra info helps some one, I spent hours trying to find the problem, dooh.

Answer (score 91):

In my case, the issue was that my teammate mentioned `*ngfor` in templates instead of `*ngFor`. Strange that there is no correct error to handle this issue (In Angular 4).

Comment: well that could have thrown me for a loop ;)

Comment: Similar: I wrote `*ngFor="let diagram if diagrams"`, notice the `if`. A "parse error" message would be better...

Comment: @klenium, you saved my day! i got that error when using `*ngFor="lang in languages"` where angular 8 expects `*ngFor="let lang of languages"`. Pretty misleading error message imo :/

Comment: I got this error because I capitalized "let."

Comment: I made the same mistake, and did'n see it, luckly i found this very quickly, Tks

Comment: THIS ^^^^! If everything looks ok in the imports check the spelling. I had *ngFor="let x or blah" - mistyped "of".

Comment: God damn, thanks i just was blind...

Answer (score 83):

You have to import `CommonModule` in the module where you are using these in-built directives like `ngFor`, `ngIf`, etc.

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
       
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
    
export class ProductModule { }
```

Comment: you say import it in the component, then show code importing it into the module

Comment: You are correct. Some directives, including ngfor, are within this module.

Comment: Worked for me. :)

Comment: You are correct ✅ ✅ ✅ ✅ ✅
It's the best answer. I had this same error. And when I import ``CommonModule`` to my new module I created and it worked.

Answer (score 71):

**There can be any possible reason:**

1. Your `module` does not have `CommonModule` in `imports[]`
2. Your `component`, where you are using `*ngFor` or `*ngIf` is not a part of any `module`.
3. You might have typo in `*ngFor` i.e. `**ngFor` or `*ngfor` etc.
4. If everything seems fine then restart your app i.e. `ng serve` or `IDE` i.e. VS Code, IntelliJ etc.

Comment: Your module does not have CommonModule in imports[], worked for me as i haven't added commonmodule in my productmodule file

Comment: Superb. forgot to add component in declaration array.

Comment: This is the answer, which covers all possible reasons for the problem. For me worked no. 2. Thanks!

Comment: restart VS code or stop npm start and start it again worked for me.

Comment: I had this error without anything wrong in the code. I just had to type (and delete) something in my templates, and it worked again.

Comment: @TimPerry you're welcome. but first would you please explain here in the comment section that what do you mean by sub-module and why we should import it in our main module. I hope to see your logical and solid reason solo for this error then we're good to add it.

Comment: This are all good suggestion but for my case it was because i have given the path of the routing instead on the module class while lazy loading and it took me a while to figure it out

Comment: @HanaWujira can you share your code sample here in comment.

Comment: for example something like this
  {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.routing.module').then(m => m.ItemsRoutingModule)
  }
when it needs to be 
 {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
  }

Answer (score 34):

For me the problem was that I did not import the custom made module `HouseModule` in my `app.module.ts`. I had the other imports.

**File: app.module.ts**

```
import { HouseModule } from './Modules/house/house.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HouseModule
  ]
})
```

Comment: Just spent over 1 hour looking for this solution. Thanks man!

Comment: Also consider relaunching 'ng serve' as sometimes new code additions are not properly picked up.

Comment: Yeah for me also, adding to app.module declarations did the trick.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Save my 2 days.

Answer (score 23):

This can also happen if you don't declare a route component in your feature module. So for example:

feature.routing.module.ts:

```
...
    {
        path: '',
        component: ViewComponent,
    }
...
```

feature.module.ts:

```
     imports: [ FeatureRoutingModule ],
     declarations: [],
```

Notice the ViewComponent is *not* in the declarations array, whereas it should be.

Comment: Thanks man, this wasn't my issue but it gave me a hint and bingo, my problem is solved!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem

Comment: This solved my issue and saved a lot of my time :)

Comment: Exactly! This should have been accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 19):

I received the error **because the component I was using wasn't registered in the   declarations: [] section** of the module.

After adding the component the error went away. I would have hoped for something less obscure than this error message to indicate the real problem.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've created an additional component in an existing .ts file and forget to register it because everything worked until I got this error.

Comment: I accidentally put my component in the providers: [] section. *facepalm*

Comment: Usually when you create a new component using ng g c 'component-name' , it registers the component in the app.module.ts. However if you open a new terminal and run the generate component command while ng serve is running on a different component, it will not register the component in the app.module.ts . This is what was causing my issue.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error,
You can fix through one of this method:

1. If you don't have any nested module

   a. Import the **CommonModule** in your **App module**

   b. Import your Component where you are adding the ***ngFor** in the **App Module**, define in **declarations**

```
// file App.modules.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent // declarations of your component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    DemoMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService, 
    CookieService, 
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ApiInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

c. If you are using the separate module file for routing then Import the **CommonModule** in your Routing module else Import the **CommonModule** in your **App module**

```
// file app.routing.modules.ts
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes), CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

2. If you have nested module then perform the 1st step in that particular module

In my case, the 2nd method solved my issue.
Hope this will help you

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to declare the component in my module.

Answer (score 16):

Things to remember:

When custom modules are used (modules other than AppModule) then it is necessary to import the common module in it.

```
yourmodule.module.ts

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[ ],
  declarations: []
})
```

Comment: Do you know why i would get that error/warning actually in chrome even after i have the commonModule on my child/custom module class?

Answer (score 14):

**Future Readers**

Check each of the following:

1. The component is declared in a *SINGLE* angular module
2. Make sure you have `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';`
3. Restart the IDE/editor
4. Restart the dev server (`ng serve`)

Comment: Just adding CommonModule doesn't fixed the issue, restarting Intelij IDE also was needed.

Comment: Also consider relaunching 'ng serve' as sometimes new code additions are not properly picked up.

Comment: restarting the server did it for me

Answer (score 8):

If you are making your own module then add CommonModule in imports in your own module

Comment: Adding CommonModule worked for me
Please improve your answer. Share steps as well

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason. I would like to add that I had to restart the server

Comment: Also make sure that you custom module are in the declaration brackets

Answer (score 6):

If you face the error in angular version 14+ where a component can stand alone, just add NgFor to the imports of your component like this :

```
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({
selector     : 'my-component',
templateUrl  : './my-component.component.html',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
standalone   : true,
imports      : [ NgFor],
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone still facing an error after trying to import `CommonModule`, try to restart the server. It surprisingly work

Comment: Just the first time. If I save, then the compailer reload and the problem still be there

Answer (score 5):

Add the component to your app.module

```
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
  
  }),
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case the component wasn't listed in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 10:

1. Add BrowserModule to the imports of your routes module.
2. Make sure that you added the component that not working to the app module declarations.

Failing to do step 2 will trigger this error!

Make sure to RESTART ng serve !!!

Answer (score 3):

**So please make sure**

1. No syntax error in directives
2. Browser (in App Module) and Common (in other/child) Modules are imported (Same what [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331563/4684417) mentioned above)
3. If you've routes in the application then route module should be imported in App Module
4. All the routed component's Module are also imported in App Module, for eg:
   app-routing.module.ts is as follows:

   const routes: Routes = [

   {path: '', component: CustomerComponent},

   {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent}

   ];

Then App module must imports modules of CustomerComponent and AdminComponent in @NgModule().

Answer (score 3):

A lot of answers seem to converge by importing `CommonModule` in other(new/custom) modules.
This step only isn't enough in all situations.

**The full solution consist in two steps:**

1. Make directives `NgIf`, `NgFor` etc visible to your project.
2. Reassemble everything in a correct way in the main component (`app.module.ts`)

**Point 1**
`BrowserModule` in main module seems to be enough for having access to `NgFor`.
[Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) stands it here: .

> *CommonModule Exports all the basic Angular directives and pipes, such as NgIf, NgForOf, DecimalPipe, and so on. Re-exported by BrowserModule,*

See also accepted answer here: [CommonModule vs BrowserModule in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular)

**Point 2** 
The only changes needed (in my case) are the followings:

1. import Module `OtherModule`
2. import Component `OtherComponent`
3. ng build  (**important!**)
4. ng serve

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        OtherModule
    ],
    declarations: [OtherComponent, AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

other.html

```
<div *ngFor='let o of others;'> 
</div>
```

other.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'other-component',
    templateUrl: './other.html'
})
export class OtherComponent {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    providers: []
})
export class OtherModule{
}
```

Comment: This helped me figure out the issue. I was missing the declaration in app.module.ts. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After using correct syntax in all of your code, please see if you have mentioned your component in the declarations of your angular module.
Something like below:

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
YourComponent
],

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, even though I had imported "**BrowserModule**" and "**CommonModule**" in "**module.ts**" it didn't work, my error was, not adding in "**NgModule.declarations**" my Component.

```
@NgModule ({
   declarations: [
     Your_Component // here
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Custom Module Needs common module**

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but *I had* the CommonModule imported. Instead I left a comma where it shouldn't be because of copy/paste when splitting a module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ShopComponent,
        ShoppingEditComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent }, <--- offensive comma
        ])
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

app.module.ts fixed and changed to: import the **BrowserModule** in your app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
  ],     
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I am started on Angular8 base live project got the above issue but When use "app-routing.module" we forget import "CommonModule". Remember to import!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
]})
```

It will solve your error.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar error (`*ngIf`) even if all my imports were OK and the component was rendered without any other error + routing was OK.

In my case `AppModule` was not including that specific module. The strange thing is that it did not complain about this, but this might be related with how Ivy works with `ng serve` (kind of loads modules according to routing, but its dependencies are not considered).

Answer (score 2):

if you already imopted (BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormsModule)
and its still not working

then all you have to do is check if the component that has the error is declared in the module

Answer (score 2):

If you have module implementation, then you must import the component and set the component in the declaration

[image]

Good Luck on your coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue after modifying a couple of components. There was no syntax error and all modules were imported, but a restart of the server fixed the issue.
The error occurred in a component, that was added several dozen successful commits ago.

Just in case someone else experiences the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think my scenario is a rare case, but I will answer anyway.

I didn't have any syntax errors. I imported BrowserModule, restated my IDE (VS Code), but I still got red lines in my template because I used `*ngFor`.

It happened because I was using an extension, `Angular Language Service`, but it was quite old. After updating it, the error stopped appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When use "app-routing.module" we forget import "CommonModule". Remember to import!

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
@NgModule({  imports: [ CommonModule]})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem because of ** instead *

```
*ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients"

**ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients"
```

Comment: Yep, VS Code seems to automatically put two stars instead of a single one.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I'm doing some unit testing on Angular 12 and ran into this.

My issue was that I was using the ng bootstrap library and testing a method that was creating a new modal with `NgbModal`.

I was getting these warnings because I had forgotten to import the component being created by the popup.

I did not need to import `FormsModule`, `CommonModule`, or `BrowserModule`.

So, if you run into these errors make sure that the component you're trying to create an instance of is listed in the imports.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I recently ran into this situation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331563/1620779) answer didn't solve my problem.

**My premises**

- I was using a custom directory structure for the project. The offending component sits inside the `components` directory.

  [image: My Directory Structure]
- The component where I found a similar error was created using CLI schematics with the 
  `--skip-import` option

  ```
    npx ng g c --skip-import ../components/my-component
  ```

**Solution**

Because I used the `--skip-import`(see note) option, I found that my component was not added to the `declarations` array in my module. Adding the component to the same solved the problem.

<sup>**Note :** Well,you can't create the component outside the app directory without this.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be thrown when the `ngFor` syntax isn't written correctly, in my case I had:

```html
<ng-template *ngForOf="let key of SomeObject; index as i">
```

And it got fixed by using the following syntax:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-key [ngForOf]="SomeObject" let-i="index">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem because of blank space in the json  data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was, that I used `const` instead of `let` inside the `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I already had **CommonModule** included in my shared module & the feature module where the component was to be used, but in my case I saved some files while server was starting (compiling) maybe that's why it did not took registry of included modules properly

=> I restarted my local server it solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I had imported CommonModule in the mycomponent.module.ts, and BrowserModule in the app.module.ts, added the MyComponent to @ngModule's declarations and reset vscode just like all the solutions had mentioned.

Finally resolved the issue by instead of iterating through data recieved through a fetch request, I mocked the elements array with hardcoded data matching the ElementModel.ts data And it worked no issues.

Realized that my ElementModel interface didn't match the data I was receiving from my fetch request.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and for me the issue was that I had mistakenly named two components the same thing

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
when doing lazy loading I mistakenly let auto complete finish the import that imported the `routing module` instead of `module`

```
 {
    path: "list-management",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import(
        "./views/pages/list-management/list-management-routing.module"
      ).then((m) => m.ListManagementRoutingModule)
}
```

Then I changed that to correct `module`

```js
    {
        path: "list-management",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import(
            "./views/pages/list-management/list-management.module"
          ).then((m) => m.ListManagementModule)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

For me, what solved the problem was to do a git clone of my project and run (as usual):

```
npm install
```