# Display Subscribe Data in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I need help in displaying the output of subscribe from an api in Angular 4. How can i do this since I wrote data.data.data but it says property data doesnt exist on type object. How would i output it in the browser? Here's my code below and the api picture below

[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-list',
  templateUrl: './news-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-list.component.css']
})
export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.newsService.getNews()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          alert("News Success");
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          alert("ERROR");
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a property in component

```
myData: any[] = [];
```

and in your subscriber function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-list',
  templateUrl: './news-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-list.component.css']
})
export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.newsService.getNews()
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          alert("News Success");
          this.myData = res.data; 
          // Where you find the array res.data or res.data.data
          console.log('res is ', res.data);
        },
        error => {
          alert("ERROR");
        });
      }
    }
```

and in your template

1) option to view JSON

```
<pre>{{myData | json}}</pre>
```

2) option to loop if you got the array

```
<div *ngFor="let d of myData">
    {{d}}
</div>
```

Comment: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
         <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of myData">
    {{d}}
</div>

Comment: check this post add Browser modulse or common module in your module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release

Comment: also to check the data try template option 1 <pre>{{myData | json}}</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Your data is type of array,

Create a variable of type any

```
myData : any;
```

and assign the data to myData,

```
this.newsService
    .getNews()
    .subscribe(
        data => {
           this.myData = data.data;
        },
        error => {
          alert("ERROR");
        }
    );
```

you can use **`ngFor`** to iterate over array and display in the HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myData">
     {{item}}
</li>
```

Comment: i think it `this.myData = data.data;`

Comment: @Sajeetharan. Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Comment: @Sajeetharan. Still on data.data,  property data doesnt exist on type object

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.newsService.getNews()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      data = data.json();
      console.log(data.data);
    },
    error => {
      alert("ERROR");
    });
```

}

the `data.json()` part is important, it converts the response into proper json so can access its data.
Now you can assign it to instance variable like this

`this.myArrayData = data.data`

inside your `subscribe()` method
Then in your template

```
<div *ngFor="let data of myArrayData">
  <!-- do whatever with the data properties -->
</div>
```

Comment: HttpClient is the new http. So i dont need to write data.json(). It is by default a json. My error now is on the html. Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("          <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of myData">     {{d}} </div>

Comment: did you try to output it in your template using json pipe like this

Comment: {{myData | json}}

Comment: Did you imported the BrowserModule in the imports[] of your NgModule (app.module.ts)?

Comment: Theres a new error. Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: make sure `myData` is any array of object not a single object, `ngFor` works on arrays

Comment: Did you consoled `myData` variable what's its value, post it in your question

Comment: I got it it lacks .data