# CommonModule vs BrowserModule in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I am pretty new to the world of Angular. What is the difference between `CommonModule` vs `BrowserModule` and why one should be preferred over the other?

Comment: It is just a convention.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#!#q-browser-vs-common-module)

> BrowserModule provides services that are essential to launch and run a
>   browser app.
>
> BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which
>   means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the
>   Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.

whereas

**CommonModule** (all the basics of Angular templating: bindings, *ngIf, *ngFor…), except in the first app module, because it’s already part of the BrowserModule

Also read **[this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407)**.

Comment: This answer is mostly copy-paste and the part that isn't needs editing to make sense. Owner, please improve your answer. Readers, the other answers to this question are much more worthy of your time.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for your feedback. I am not sure what will provide better explanation than the docs (tbh other answers also have the same link) I will try to improve as you mentioned

Answer (score 66):

What you have to understand is, with Angular, you create modular application and there are two types of modules. *One is root module and another is feature module.*

- Root module imports the BrowserModule (if you are rendering in browser). This has the same stuffs as `CommonModule` but also stuffs that are used for rendering.
- Now if you are creating a feature module, since you already have BrowserModule imported in your root module, it does not make sense and it's an overhead to import the Browser module in your feature module. Also, importing CommonModule  frees feature modules for use on any target platform (e.g. native mobile platform), not just browsers.
  That's why you import `CommonModule` in your feature modules and `BrowserModule` in your root module.

Comment: Excellent answer!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

The root application module, **AppModule**, imports **BrowserModule** so that it can have all the services that are essential to launch and run a browser app.

Components in the **AppModule** also need to have access to the Angular directive(Arrtibute Directive, Structural Directive) such as **ngIf*, **ngFor* and **ngSwitch* etc. and these directive are available in **CommonModule** which is automatically exported by the **BrowserModule**. This is why we have access
to the directives in the components defined in **AppModule**.

And according to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule)

Only root application module, **AppModule** , should import **BrowserModule** and all other [feature module](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) should import **CommonModule** because we only need the Angular directives in feature module and not the services that are required to launch the app(Which are already available in RootModule).

According to [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html):

When it comes to components, pipes and directives, every feature module should import its own dependencies disregarding if the same dependencies were imported in the root module or in any other feature module.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the latest update for Angular 13**

In Angular, we have two types of modules - Root Module and Feature Module.

Feature modules mainly imports `CommonMudule` which contains basic directives and pipes such as `NgIf`, `NgClass`, and `DatePipe`.

Root module mainly imports `BrowserModule` which basically contains all the directives and pipes of `CommonMudule`, along with that it also provides the features to render the Angular Application in any Browser.

To conclude, the `BrowserModule` should only be imported once and that too in the root module. For all the other feature modules, it is enough to import the `CommonMudule`.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the definitions of 'BrowserModule' and 'CommonModule', my suggestion for using them is something like this,
You should have the 'BrowserModule' in application module level, 'AppModule':

```
app.module.ts: 
    
         import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
         imports: [
                BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' })]
```

having the 'CommonModule' in custom component level, in a SharedModule among the other common modules that you use in the project:

```
shared.module.ts: 
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    
 imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule     
      ], 
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule]
```

Then inject this 'SharedModule' into any other custom modules, like this:

```
login.module.ts:  

     import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
        imports: [
            SharedModule]
```