# NullInjectorError: No provider for NgZone! (Angular 6 library)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ngzone

### Summary

I created an Angular 6 library, but I get an error when I try to use it outside of the project in which it was created. This looks like a lot of code, but it's mostly boilerplate generated by the CLI.

### Minimal Working Test Case

I created a very basic library with the Angular 6 CLI.

```bash
ng new mylib 
cd mylib
ng generate library example
ng build --prod example
```

I can then add  `<lib-example></lib-example>` to `src/app/app.component.html`, run `ng serve`, and see the example component works as expected.

Next I edit `projects/example/src/lib/example.component.ts` to add an an `*ng-if="true"` to the `<p>` tag.

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-example',
  template: `
    <p *ng-if="true"> <!-- this line was changed -->
      example works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

To get the `ngIf` directive, I import `BrowserModule`, so my `projects/example/src/lib/example.module.ts` looks like this:

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; // added

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule // added
  ],
  declarations: [ExampleComponent],
  exports: [ExampleComponent]
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

Rebuild:

```
ng build --prod example
```

My component doesn't do anything useful yet, but it works as long as I use it within the same project I used to create it.

### Minimal Non-Working Test Case

Let's try using the library in a different app. I start by generating a new app that lives in the same directory as the app that contains the library.

```
ng new myapp
```

Then I add `<lib-example></lib-example>` to `myapp/src/app/app.component.html` and import the library in `myapp/src/app/app.module.ts`, so that it looks like this.

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ExampleModule } from "../../../mylib/dist/example"; // added

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     ExampleModule // added
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Error Message

When I browse to the app, I get the following error in the console.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationRef -> NgZone]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApplicationRef -> NgZone]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgZone!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1060)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1298)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1139)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1298)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1139)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8377)
    at _createClass (core.js:8430)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8394)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try importing  `CommonModule` in `AppModule`.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds reasonable as `ngIf` is defined in `CommonModule`, but importing the dependency didn't change anything. Nor did it help to import into `ExampleModule`. If I'm not mistaken, [CommonModule is included in BrowserModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular) so adding it explicitly has no effect.

Comment: When I build the app I'm getting warnings from Webpack. I'm guessing there's a common cause, but I'm not sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614615/angular-6-the-result-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression

Comment: That is pulling my hair for the 6 days now. can it be related to AOT and UMD? I am not sure

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know why. But the problem is with importing the `BrowserModule`. Do not import it into your library module and it should work.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
//import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; // added

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   // BrowserModule // removed
  ],
  declarations: [ExampleComponent],
  exports: [ExampleComponent]
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

I have been in this for a very long time and removed the imports in my library module one by one. It was the `BrowserModule`.

I think this should answer your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614615/angular-6-the-result-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression).

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I mean do not import it in the example module. I just updated the answer

Comment: The `BrowserModule` is needed for `*ngIf`. Without it, the project doesn't compile.

Comment: You can use CommonModule. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular

Comment: @Patrick: I guess swapping CommonModule for BrowserModule to enable *ngIf (not *ng-if as seen in your code) to be recognised in the Library HTML didn't have any effect on the "no provider for NgZone" warning/error.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to add the following in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    },
```

Please note the path is `./node_modules`, some suggest `../node_modules`, the latter did not work for me.

Hope this will help someone. It took me a very long time to get to the solution. Thanks to: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11883

Comment: This definitely did the trick for me with Webpack 4 and Angular 8.