# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript

When adding an ngFor to a div I get the following warning and it appears to be stopping my HTML from rendering.

I only have the one module on my app and the BrowserModule is imported in the imports which seemed to fix the problem for most people but it's not working for me.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals" class="animal-row">
    <img />
    <div class="animal-info">
        <p class="animal-name"><i class="fad fa-monkey"></i> Alfie (Alifie-Moon)</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="species" class="col">
                <p id="species-text"><i class="fad fa-paw-claws"></i> <span>Skunk</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p><i class="fad fa-paw"></i> <span>American</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p><i class="fad fa-home-heart"></i> <span>01.01.01</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p><i class="fad fa-watch-fitness"></i> <span>3 Years</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p><i class="fad fa-hotel"></i> <span>1-A</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p><i class="fad fa-smile"></i> <span>Good</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
// Angular & 3rd Part Imports
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastNotificationsModule } from 'ngx-toast-notifications';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
// Providers
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
// Services
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { ModuleService } from './_services/module.service';
// Components
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SubnavComponent } from './subnav/subnav.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      LoginComponent,
      DashboardComponent,
      SubnavComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      CommonModule
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      ToastNotificationsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
            tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
            blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
         }
      })
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider,
      ModuleService
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know if this is relevant but I did have a file called module.ts (that was an interface) that I renamed to navLinks, just in case it created a conflict - is it possible Angular thought that was another module?

Comment: I believe you need CommonModule

Comment: @Phix - Tried that but still get the same error

Comment: You are missing `,` after `CommonModule` is that typo in code or in this question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I hadn't declared my component I was working on in app.module.ts - as soon as that was declared this resolved the issue

Comment: I saw ` AppComponent,` in declaration  section of code

Comment: thank you so much .. you saved my hours..

Answer (score 18):

**There can be any one of the reasons:**

1. Your `module` does not have `CommonModule` in `imports[]`
2. Your `component`, where you are using `*ngFor`, is not a part of any `module` i.e. `appModule` imported `CommonModule` because `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` etc are initialized in `CommonModule`.
3. You might have syntax error in `*ngFor` i.e. `**ngFor` or `*ngfor` etc. typo.
4. If everything seems fine then restart your `IDE` i.e. VS Code, IntelliJ etc.

Comment: I want to share an example of second point. my main component will dynamically generate AlertComponent when meet an error, and the AlertComponet is using ngFor directive. but I didn't declare AlertComponent in declarations.

Comment: Oh WOW!  #1.   You made me so happy! :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` in `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
   import: [BrowserModule,CommonModule]
})
```

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular)

Comment: Added the CommonModule, but same problem

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Are you sure you are adding in correct `module.ts`  ? Can you please double check and confirm

Comment: I'll edit my post above to show where I've added the CommonModule

Comment: I don't know if this is relevantbut I did have a file called module.ts (that was an interface) that I renamed to navLinks, just in case it created a conflict - is it possible Angular thought that was another module?

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf : Nope . is should not create conflict. You need to add `NgModule` to let angular know that its a module

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever we break our application to have a multilevel parent and child structure of modules, we may face this issue. In my application there is the main app module known as app.module.ts and also other child modules that we’re unable to access this directive globally.

To resolve this issue we need to import **BrowserModule** in the application’s main module i.e app.module.ts file and also import **CommonModule** in the child module.

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
@NgModule({  imports: [ CommonModule]})
```

Comment: I only have the one app.module.ts file - as far as I'm aware I haven't added any other modules

Comment: I don't know if this is relevantbut I did have a file called module.ts (that was an interface) that I renamed to navLinks, just in case it created a conflict - is it possible Angular thought that was another module?

Comment: can you create stackblitz  for this ?