# “Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have the following code in my html modal component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let school of schools">
   {{school.name}}
<ng-container>
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
“Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'
```

I've looked at other people's solutions online who suggest importing forms module, reactive forms module and common module, but I already have these imported in the modal module

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The ngFor directive is exported from the CommonModule, try importing the corresponding module to your app module imports or to the corresponding module in use.

Comment: Thanks @Francisco Bernad. But I already have the CommonModule imported in both my modal.module, and in my app.module files

Answer (score 0):

Add BrowserModule in your app.module.ts. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kws5vb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports:[ BrowserModule],
```

So, you should import BrowserModule in app.module whereas CommonModule in feature modules [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular) is a good read on this topic