# Nested NgFor looping over an array of objects

Tags: html, angular, angular5, ngfor

I am using angular 5.
I am trying to use the following array in nested ngFor loops in html

Object:

```
    [
    {
        "copyFromDay": "Sunday",
        "days": [
           "Monday",
           "Tuesday",
           "Wednesday",
           "Thursday",
           "Friday",
           "Saturday"
        ]
    },
    {
        "copyFromDay": "Monday",
        "days": [
            "Sunday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        ]
    }//,....   
]
```

HTML:

```
<table>
        ....
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let sourceDay of copyToArray">
            <label>sourceDay.copyFromDay</label>
                <ul><li *ngFor="let day of sourceDay.days">
                <label><input type="checkbox" />{{day}}</label>
                </li></ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I am getting the following parsing error:

*Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.* 
[image]

I have imported **BrowserModule** and **CommonModule** in the app.module.ts
I am doing this so that the user can copy a schedule from any day of the week to the rest of the week.

**EDIT:** 
Actual HTML from my code:

```
<td *ngFor = "let sourceDay of copyFromArray">
    <div class="copytodiv">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-raised copytobtn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Copy to <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li *ngfor="let day of sourceDay.days">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> {{day}}
                        </label>
                    </div>                                                        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I can modify the array to more optimal structure for achieving this task. Please let me know if anything is wrong with it's structure.

Comment: Check this and also make sure your key names are correctly used https://stackoverflow.com/a/40331563/1339516

Comment: try `<li *ngFor="let day of sourceDay"><input type="checkbox" /><label>{{day.day}}</label>` and see if that works.. Im not sure you can do `sourceDay.day` in an `*ngFor`

Comment: @JuvenileSnow, We can do `sourceDay.days` as shown in the demo by Ashish Ranjan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spelling `*ngFor` wrong. It's `*ngFor` with the capital F not `*ngfor` as you did in the li.So basically. change

```
 <li *ngfor="let day of sourceDay.days">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> {{day}}
                        </label>
                    </div>                                                        
                </li>
```

to

```
<li *ngFor="let day of sourceDay.days">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> {{day}}
                        </label>
                    </div>                                                        
                </li>
```

Comment: you were right. As this is simple typo issue. Dumb me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the Module imports, 
The only mistake I see is, you have referred `sourceDay.day` instead of `sourceDay.days`, and you have missed interpolation for label`sourceDay.copyFromDay` I implemented your code and its running fine for me, see the example here:
[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-athkwe)

Comment: The interpolation is a typo here. Strangely what is working in your demo isn't working in my project.

Comment: In your question, you have said that your error was: `Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.`. Is this the actual error or there's some typo in `ngforOf`? Have you used `ngforOf` somewhere instead of `ngFor`?

Comment: I have only used ngFor but not ngForOf anywhere

Comment: So this means there's a typo in the `error message` you have added to the question?

Comment: No the error message is showing ngForOf. Please check the screenshot.

Comment: @Kaushik: Oh, sorry, I guess the error shows like: `ngforOf` itself. Okay, do you have other modules too in your app? If yes, then add  the `CommonModule` in the `imports[]` of the module in which your current working component is declared.

Comment: Yes, but have you added to the `imports` of the module in which your component is declared? Is your `Component` declared in the `AppModule` or some other `module`?

Comment: as Nuru pointed it out, it was a typo in my code. Sorry to make you waste so much time in this.

Answer (score 0):

1st wrap the li within a ul

2nd sourceDay.days, you have missed the s on the end

3th the second label should surround the input and the day

Comment: All of them were my mistakes while typing. Actual code in the project is similar with some styles added. But still getting the same error.