# mat-option in angular material not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use angular-material with angular-6

My material.module.ts is like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}




<mat-form-field>
       <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                            {{ food.viewValue }}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

It is giving error

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.
1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (final release)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to export all the Material related modules,

```
 exports: [
 ]
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-edn9bs?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score -1):

in providers try to add  ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher