# Angular Material: selection list example not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use an Angular Material (7.0) selection list [as described here](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists).

The example code snippet on the page is

```
  <mat-selection-list #shoes>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
      {{shoe}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>

  <p>
    Options selected: {{shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
  </p>
```

with the `typesOfShoes` defined in the TS file, as described in their snippet:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Makes sense to me, but when I try to compile I get the **Error**:

```
ERROR in: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-list-option'.
1. If 'mat-list-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForOf' input,
 then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-list-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'
 to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
etc.
```

I have imported `MatListModule` into my app module.

I see no further modules related to list options to import.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (final release)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `BrowserModule` (or `CommonModule` if it's a child module) in `@NgModule()`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
})
```

Comment: My app module already has `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'`.  My sharedModule imports `CommonModule` and my `MaterialModule` (with all the material module imports/exports).  All my other material components work.

Comment: actually, my shared module imported common module but did not export it.  That fixed it.

Comment: as of today this doesnt work
`Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'BrowserModule'.ts(2305)`