# Angular ngFor not working with material since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, angular-material

angular ngfor can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of

```
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 shadow-sm bg-white rounded leftSideBar">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
                    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
                        {{i.name}}
                        <mat-radio-button [value]="i.id"></mat-radio-button>
                    </li>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you imported CommonModule or BrowserModule on the component's module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (final release)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `BrowserModule` to `imports: []` in `AppModule`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/common';
..
..
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  ..
})
```