# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container', Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular

do someone have some idea about this problem?(i use angular)

<ng-container *ngIf="action != 'Delete'; else elseTemplate">

<ng-template #elseTemplate>

and the same code is working in another windows and it is why i don't have idea why it isn't here too.
i receive that at error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'
Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

thanks in advance for suggestion

Comment: check if `CommonModule` is imported in  your `app.module`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (final release)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)