# Angular HTML is not showing total features from openlayers

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

I'm building application using Angular and Openlayers. I have a function working on zoomend which gives me a total number of features in the current box. I'm able to get the output in console.log but not in HTML.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'olnew';
  map;
  features 
  featlength
  ngOnInit(){
    this.map = new Map({
      target:'map',
      view: new View({
        projection:'EPSG:4326',
        center:[-94.18246640804583, 34.96110848844138],
        zoom:9
      }),
      layers:[
        new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
        })
      ]
    })
   
    this.map.on('moveend', function(e){
      var mapp = e.map
      console.log(mapp.getView().calculateExtent())
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp%3Astates&bbox='+mapp.getView().calculateExtent()[0]+','+mapp.getView().calculateExtent()[1]+','+mapp.getView().calculateExtent()[2]+','+mapp.getView().calculateExtent()[3]+'&outputFormat=application%2Fjson')
      .then(res => 
        res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.features = data.features
        
        this.featlength = data.features.length
        console.log('feat lent ='+ this.featlength)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<div>Total feat = {{ featlength }}</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let feat of features">
    {{ feat.id }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have added browserModule and CommonModule as well

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the error if you have at the top of the console? `Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'` - this should be dealt will, and **will** probably fix what's wrong with the rest of the page.

What you need to do is to make sure you import `BrowserModule` in the application's main module, and also import `CommonModule` in the child module (where this component is found)

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release)

Comment: Yeah, I already added BrowserModule and CommonModule . I'm using *ngFor instead of *ngfor. The thing is when I add static value to the variables, (e.g. features = [{id:1},{id:2}]) , then I can see the li popping up value. but for some reasons, it is not showing in my function :/

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the html getting rendered before a value is assigned to the variable & not getting updated once it is assigned a value. Adding an ngIf condition to the  like such should fix this.

`<div *ngIf="featlength ">Total feat = {{ featlength }}</div>`

Comment: Tried *ngIf .. No Luck :(

Comment: What do you see on inspecting the html ?