# Angular11 - NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: angular, angular11

the template TR not displayed, and generates an error : NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.
I don't understand why.
I am in Angular 11 and navigator Chrone

[Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRvcl.png)
html :

> ```
>     <div>
>     <h1 class="module-title">Job logs</h1>
>     <span class="sp-notice">the time zone is set on GMT</span>
>     <div class="container">
>         <table class="table table-striped">
>             <thead>
>               <tr>
>                 <th scope="col">#JobFirst</th>
>                 <th scope="col">Last start</th>
>                 <th scope="col">Last Finish</th>
>                 <th scope="col">Time</th>
>               </tr>
>             </thead>
>             <tbody>
>               <tr *ngFor="let item of jobs">
>                 <th>{{ item.JobName }}</th>
>                 <td>{{ item.LastStartOperation }}</td>
>                 <td>{{ item.LastFinishOperation }}</td>
>                 <td>{{ item.Time }}</td>
>               </tr>
>             </tbody>
>           </table>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

this is the content of the file component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-joblog',
  templateUrl: './joblog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./joblog.component.css']
})
export class JoblogComponent implements OnInit {

  jobs = [
    {
      JobName:'Client_Timer',
      LastFinishOperation:'2021-12-01',
      LastStartOperation:'2021-12-01',
      Time:'0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs'
    },    
    {
      JobName:'Truc_Astuce',
      LastFinishOperation:'2021-12-01',
      LastStartOperation:'2021-12-01',
      Time:'0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs'
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is the contentof the App.module.tsfile :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import{ HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { JoblogComponent } from './joblog/joblog.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path:'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  {path:'joblogs', component: JoblogComponent},
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your `JoblogComponent` ? I don't see it in the `declarations` array

Comment: I don't see the `CommonModule` imported in `AppModule`. As I remember `*ngFor` is a part of the `CommonModule`.

Comment: Many thanks @eko
With the declaration, it is better ! (I am a beginner in angular)

Comment: Ah cool, I'll add it as an answer then :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add the component to the declarations array:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    JoblogComponent
  ],
```