# Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. error coming for no reason

Tags: html, angular

this is my code that I was stuck on:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item in items">{{item.Title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `*ngFor="let item of items"`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf.

Comment: Normally this would be a problem with forgetting to import `CommonModule` in a feature module. Since it appears to be a typo instead, I have voted to close as a typo instead of as a duplicate. For reference: [Forgetting to import `CommonModule`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release) and [Forgetting to import `FormsModule`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is issue with the `*ngFor` syntax. Do like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.Title}}</li>
</ul>
```

`in` is replaced with `of`