# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. CommonModule and BrowserModule are imported

Tags: angular

Really odd problem. I'm getting an error when I try to use *ngFor on a tr element:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of productsData">
<!-- some Code -->
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In my component.ts file I have this:

```
productsData: ProductDataModel[] = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.SubscribeForData();
  }

  SubscribeForData() {
    this.productService.GetAllProducts().subscribe(result => {
      if (result.success) {
        this.productsData = result.model;
      }
    });
  }
```

This particular component is in a child module so has the CommonModule imported in the @NgModule from '@angular/common' and the app.module.ts has BrowserModule imported from '@angular/platform-browser'.

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Module which component is declared in:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AllProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserAccountsRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
})
```

I have used *ngFor else where without any issues.

The angular version I am running is 14.0.4

Comment: Try importing the CommonModule in the same module where you declare this component.

Comment: I have as detailed in the question

Comment: Can you please add to your question what the `app.module.ts` and your lazy loaded module look like?

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331549/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-final-release

Comment: Robin, this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have added the modules to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're not importing the child module in your AppModule.

Comment: I haven't needed to do that on other components which are in a different child module and it works fine. Would that really make a difference? Apparently, it does.....

Answer (score 1):

```
cafe.component.html:13  NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container' (used in the '_CafeComponent' component template).
    1. If 'ng-container' is an Angular component and it has the 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
    2. If 'ng-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

I got a similar error message and adding the feature module into app.modules imports array solved my problem.